# ZeroBrane IDE - "run to cursor" (Ctrl+Shift+F10) mode *sometimes* not working during debug

Tags: debugging, lua, ide, torch, zerobrane

I use ZeroBrane studio (ZBstudio) for debugging Lua code when working with the Torch framework.

A weird issue occurs at times. When debugging, sometimes I want to run the code all the way until it encounters a breakpoint. This specific mode does not work at times (sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't; I can't figure out why).

When it doesn't work, nothing happens when I press the relevant button in the GUI (or Ctrl+Shift+F10). I can go line-by-line (Shift+F10) when this happens, the line-by-line mode is not affected.

Sometimes when this happend, restarting the ZeroBrane IDE program fixed it, other times it remains persistant.

Not sure if anyone else encountered this strange behaviour. Thanks in any case.

Comment: There is no simple answer, but I haven't seen this problem. What's your OS? Can you try without any plugins (other than the Torch one)? You may want to set `debugger.verbose=true` in the config to see what breakpoints are set and whether the debugger are running or not when it should be suspended at the (temporary) breakpoint after run-to-cursor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I found that in my case using "Step out of the current function (Ctrl+F10)" does the same job. I am currently debugging a script, so that's probably why.
Not really a fix but works for me for the time being.

btw, I am running ZBStudio from within a docker. I don't see how this would explain the strange behavior I mentioned, but I figured it might be relevant.

Comment: I'd be interested to see what commands are being sent and received (shown when `debugger.verbose=true` is set) when you press Ctrl+Shift+F10 and the result is not what you expect.